# How to TeX like this

Tags: packages

[This](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~lramos/mi667/ref/07casella03.pdf) page is what I am referring to. I have often wondered how journals TeX their articles like this, and the trick that I have tried in the past of saving the pdf and looking at the info with Preview (on a Mac) doesn't provide me with any additional information.

Comment: And what specific you are trying to do? The article doesn't look very complex or non-standard.

Comment: well given the journal it's a preprint from I assume it was made with the elsart class as documented in the journal submission instructions. It's using several commercial fonts though so the submission draft prepared with the class wouldn't look quite the same http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/505561/authorinstructions#N10F04

Comment: Trying to get a times new roman look but `txfonts` makes my math kind of weird. Do you have a suggestion for a good template that has nice math, but uses TNR font for text?

Comment: Elsevier uses an in-house LaTeX document class that's available in TeX Live: `elsarticle.cls`; the example documents in the distribution show similar output, apart from the header in the first page and the font (Elsevier uses its own).

Comment: @egreg could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept? Thanks for the hint, I never thought to check the journal page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elsevier uses an in-house LaTeX document class that's available in TeX Live and on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle): `elsarticle.cls`; the example documents in the distribution show similar output, apart from the header in the first page and the font (Elsevier uses its own).

You can obtain a font quite similar to Elsevier's by loading also

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

The class is released under the LPPL and I've found no statement that it can be used only for submission to Elsevier's journals.